# adf - jpa datacontrol is not getting updated data on doing insert

Tags: oracle-adf

I am using ADF with  JPA as model 
I have a page in which i am using button to add a row in to database
My actionlistionar calling function

```
public void addAns() {
    OperationBinding op1 =
        BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry().getOperationBinding("QuestionsFindByQid");
    questions = (Questions) op1.getResult();
    BigDecimal aid = maxAnsID();
    Answer = new Answers();
    Answer.setAnsvalue(AnsValue);
    Answer.setUsers(user);
    Answer.setQuestions(questions);
    Answer.setGroups(questions.getGroups2());
    Answer.setAnsdate(date);
    Answer.setAid(aid);
    // op =BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry().getOperationBinding("Create");
    //op.execute();
    OperationBinding op = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry().getOperationBinding("persistAnswers");
    op.getParamsMap().put("answers", Answer);
    op.execute();

    System.out.println(op.getResult());
    op1 = BindingContext.getCurrent().getCurrentBindingsEntry().getOperationBinding("QuestionsFindByQid");
    op1.execute();
   FacesMessage message =
        new FacesMessage("answer added succesfully ");
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(user.getUsername(), message);
}
```

i am calling persist method for insertion
i have a table in which i need data to be updated on insert and i have tried re-executing binding method but the QuestionsFindByQid is not getting updated data 
i have checked my entity after persist and i am getting updated data in my entity

can some one help me please

Answer (score 0):

Krishna, what build of JDev/ADF are you on?

The simplest answer may be that whatever class is implementing `persistAnswers()` is not implicitly committing the operation. A `persist()` call itself updates the JPA persistence context but not the DB. To apply the changes, it needs to be committed.

JDev provides wizards to create either an EJB session bean or a simple POJO that will act as a facade to handle the transaction. This evolved in the last few releases, and the latest (12.1.3) provides turn-key solutions for CRUD operations using both EJB and POJO facades over JPA entities.

Comment: hello jon_w thanks for the comment but i found out that not all the entity involved are updating so i have used em.refresh on the rest of the entities and every thing is working now